# Display provinces (like states) in a Map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I want to draw the provinces (of Spain) with colors,  i'm looking for the methods to this but i  don't have clear.

I found a way to do with kml files (but i don't find the kml) but i need others alternatives (use quartz2d, do it by hand, etc...)

Someone help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this would help you but this is what I did sometime back... have a look.. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9190777/919545

Comment: Hi Ankit, thanks for you r answer, how can parse the kml? with kmlparser?

Comment: mine was a dummy application so I just extracted the co-ordinates for the boundaries and hard coded them but yeah you can parse them using KMLParser..